# Union initialisation in a struct

Tags: c++, struct, g++, unions

I've been browsing stackoverflow concerning the problem of initialising a union in a struct but I didn't manage to get it right.

Here is my struct

```
typedef struct dc_netif_filter {
    unsigned char filter_type;  
    union {
        uint32_t itf_nb;
        char * buf; 
    } value;
} dc_netif_filter_t;
```

In my code, i have tried to use :

```
dc_netif_filter_t netif = {DC_NETIF_SELECT_NAME,{{0, "tun"}}};
```

which gives error: braces around scalar initializer for type ‘uint32_t’

and

```
dc_netif_filter_t netif = {DC_NETIF_SELECT_NAME,{0, "tun"}};
```

which gives error: too many initializers for ‘dc_netif_filter::< anonymous union>’

How do i declare such a dc_netif_filter_t ?

I'm using g++ on ubuntu. Note that the dc_netif_filter_t isn't a struct that I can modify as it comes from a third party project.

**EDIT : as I've been explained, i can only initialise one field. The problem is that with

```
dc_netif_filter_t netif = {DC_NETIF_SELECT_NAME,"tun0"};
```

I get a conversion error :  invalid conversion from ‘const char*’ to ‘uint32_t

Thanks

Comment: You only initialise one member of a union.

Comment: You don't want to initialize *all* the members of the union; how about: `dc_netif_filter_t netif = {DC_NETIF_SELECT_NAME, "tun"};`

Comment: then how do i set buf to "tun" and then 0 to itf_nb ?

Comment: You don't. Unions aren't structures. BTW, your code looks like C, not C++.

Comment: @trojanfoe i get " error: invalid conversion from ‘const char*’ to ‘uint32_t’
 "

Comment: @David Hammen it is from a C header used in a C++ program

Comment: You don't; only one member is valid at any one time (therefore you normally have a flag outside the `union` which tells you which member is being used); in this case `filter_type`.

Comment: @djfoxmccloud: I think in C++ you can only initialize the first member of a union anyway. C++11 might have changed that, not sure. But regardless of what you can or can't initialize, certainly only one member of a union is valid at any one time, so there's no way you can have `itf_nb` equal to 0 and `buf` equal to `"tun"` simultaneously. You must have misunderstood what the struct `dc_netif_filter` is for.

Comment: @trojanfoe I get a conversion error, see my edit please !

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As the compiler says, `too many initializers for ‘dc_netif_filter::< anonymous union>’`.

Initialize only one field, not both.

Use the name of the field to initialize it properly:

```
dc_netif_filter_t netif = {DC_NETIF_SELECT_NAME, { buf: "tun0" }};
```

Comment: If I initialize only the field i'm interested in with what is my edit (see the OP edited) I get a conversion error

Comment: I believe that this is a non-standard g++ extension.

Comment: @Nick I have no idea. It's called `Designated Initializers` in ISO C99. Probably the same in C++ but I'm not certain.

Comment: @Soohjun Thank you, the edited version works ! You sir, deserve some love ;)

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you are trying to initialize your structure to indicate that the `buf` member is to be used, and that the value of that `buf` should be `"tun"`. Since C++ before C++11 lacks *designated initializers*, you cannot do it with an initializer: only the first field of the `union` can be initialized, so you need to do your assignment in code:

```
static get_dc_netif_filter_t() {
    static c_netif_filter_t netif = {DC_NETIF_SELECT_NAME, {0}};
    if (netif.value.itf_nb == 0) {
        netif.value.buf = "tun";
    }
    return netif;
}
```

C++11 lets you do it like this:

```
dc_netif_filter_t netif = {DC_NETIF_SELECT_NAME, { .buf = "tun"}};
```

Comment: I get : expected primary-expression before ‘.’ token
Is there a compiler option I am missing ?

Comment: @djfoxmccloud try `-std=c++11`

Comment: This is incorrect. Designated Initializers are not in C++11. They are currently proposed for C++20 (see http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/p0329r4.pdf). However, they do seem to currently work in GCC, Clang as well as MSVC.

Answer (score 1):

This works under g++ 4.7.0:

```
dc_netif_filter_t netif = {DC_NETIF_SELECT_NAME, {.buf="tun"}};
```

Although *designated initializers* are supposed to be C only, not C++!  Maybe it's a GNU extension?

I guess the best (most compatible) way is to assign the members after initialization:

```
dc_netif_filter_t netif;
netif.itf_nb = DC_NETIF_SELECT_NAME;
netif.value.buf = "TUN";
```

Comment: I get : expected primary-expression before ‘.’ token
Is there a compiler option I am missing ?

Comment: No, I used no command line options.  I guess it must be dependent on compiler version; as I say it's not supposed to work in C++ anyway.

Comment: I understand that it is not "supposed to work in C++", the thing is that I need to compile this code "as is" ;) With g++  4.4.3 it doesn't work, i'll try upgrading